# Как правильно делать импорт модулей, чтобы скрипт можно было запустить самостоятельно и из другого скрипта?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такая файловая структура:

```
root
|--project1
|    |--__init__.py
|    |--subrunner.py
|    |--proc.py
|--project2
|--projectN
|--runner.py
```

#### runner.py

```
from project1.subrunner import foo  

foo()
```

#### subrunner.py

Эта версия импорта:

```
from proc import bar

def foo():
    bar()
```

позволяет запустить `subrunner`, но при запуске `runner` получаем ошибку: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proc'`.
А эта версия импорта:

```
from .proc import bar
```

относительный через точку, наоборот. Позволяет запустить `runner`, но при запуске `subrunner` получаем ошибку: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.proc'; '__main__' is not a package`

Как правильно делать импорт, чтобы работало и при запуске `runner`, и при запуске `subrunner`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Правильный" вариант такой:

```
from .proc import bar
```

При этом subrunner у меня выглядит так:

```
from .proc import bar


def foo():
    print('foo')
    bar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Запускать subrunner нужно с ключом `-m` интерпретатора:

```
python -m project1.subrunner
```

Выводит:

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что изначально, это самостоятельные, отдельные программы, с говорящим названием папки. Для которой запуск "извне", `utils> python -m BookManager.manager`, вместо `utils\BookManager> python -m manager` выглядит чужеродно. Но иногда, они могут быть подключены в другие программы, в роли, чем-то напоминающей плагин. Предполагаю, что нужно определенным образом написать `__init__`, но куда копать, не знаю.

Comment: По мне так `python -m BookManager.manager` вполне нормально выглядит, не сильно отличается, например от `python BookManager/manager.py`. Дело привычки. При желании можно импорт в `try - except ModuleNotFoundError` можно обернуть. Также посмотрите на ответы к этому вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/4752653

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и ссылку. `try - except`, несмотря на внешнюю привлекательность, не подходит. Модулей в программе может быть больше и связи между ними сложнее. Придется для каждого импорта писать обертку. Проблема решилась написанием standalone.py внутри каталога, с расширением sys.path и относительным импортом `from project1.subrunner import foo`, полностью аналогичным runner-у верхнего уровня.

Comment: А еще лучше, добавить расширение списка `sys.path` в `__init__.py`, что исключит любые модификации исходного когда (остается обычный абсолютный импорт) и написание оберток, при использования программы в роли пакета.

Comment: @Lecron, я думаю, это можно как ответ оформить

Answer (score 0):

Если в файл `__init__.py` каталога `Project1` поместить такой код:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

то при использовании программы в роли пакета (запуск `runner.py`), не придется редактировать импорты, сохранив их абсолютными `from proc import bar`.